# Godaddy dns and hosting configuration causing issues with server sending mail

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, godaddy

We have a dedicated server setup at Godaddy which we use to host several client sites.

One of our clients has their domain registered with Godaddy, and is using Godaddy to handle all of their email, so they have a DNS zonefile already setup.

When we moved their hosting to our dedicated server mentioned above, we had them simply swap the IP address in their "A" record from the old hosting IP, to our dedicated server's IP.

From our end, in the hosting setup Plesk control panel, we created a "customer" and "domain" record for them, and setup their content on our server. Then we simply put the NS records we got from THEM (from their Godaddy DNS setup) into place for their hosting setup.

Everything works fine, until a script on the server (call it "somedomain.com") tries to send email to someone@somedomain.com . It never gets received. It can send to other email addresses, so we know its NOT a script error.

I think its because the hosting setup, the record we created via our control panel for the client's website, ONLY has 2 Nameservers associated with it. The server doesn't any "mail" configuration at all, because it has no DNS zonefile it would normally use to determine that.

Do I have to "turn off" the DNS that the client has setup under his Godaddy account and "move" all that information to a DNS record that is on my hosting server?

Confused as all heck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They likely need an MX record to specify where their mail server is.  Without it, mail should be delivered to your server.  If that is the case, it won't help to move their DNS to your servers.

The MX record can be added in the GoDaddy configuration file.  It needs to point to an A record for the mail server.  Commonly mail is sent to a subdomain named mail or smtp.  Adding a name record for mail with their old IP addres, and setting up an MX record on the domain pointing to mail.somedomain.com should solve the problem.

If you do want to move their DNS to other servers you need to change the NS records in GoDaddy.  Setting up your own DNS servers correctly is not that simple.  I would stick with GoDaddy.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I'm sure it would work on an ordinary server setup, but it turns out this issue was caused by the Plesk control panel implemented by the Godaddy setup - there was a setting that is set to "on" as default by Plesk to tell it to handle mail. I disabled the setting and my scripts send to the server's email addresses correctly now.